# a issue about CSS align center apply in the browser

Tags: html, css, web

Code like this:

```
.element {   
     position: absolute; 
     left: 0; 
     top: 0; 
     right: 0; 
     bottom: 0;   
     margin: auto;    /* **if i add this ,element will align center**  */  
}
```

How can **left**, **right**, **top**, **bottom** all equal 0? doesn't it mean distance equal 0? I can't understand how this CSS work.

Comment: Uhm? The `margin: auto` doesn't change anything. What browser are you using? Are you sure you have not set the width and height of the div elsewhere?

Comment: en,i use chome now ,sorry , i describe it particular  if i delete left,right,top,bottom=0;only margin:auto; it doesn't work. i must use left,right,bottom,top=0;and margin:auto; can work prefect.

Comment: so i can't understand why left,right,top,bottom=0;play a important role in there,  doesn't it mean  the distance of my element  to four side,   I put my element(div) in a bigger <div>